# Disable iOS Pinning

Tags: xcode, security, code-signing-certificate, frida, apple-sign-in

As part of an exercise at work, I have been trying to turn off the iOS pinning on an application using Frida on a non-jailbroken device. I have followed multiple tutorials online and so far I can only do this while the device is connected via USB - and the project is running via Xcode. My first question is, how can I now do this without the use of USB and Xcode on the same device?

The next thing I am trying to do is to add Frida to an IPA file I have from another published app, resign the IPA file and then see how that works. Unfortunately I am unable to sign the IPA file as, as soon as I add and sign the Frida gadget and zip the IPA, it returns the following error:

```
Error: Invalid IPA: /Users/XXXX/Downloads/patchedapp.ipa.80da28bf-bf15-483e-a8f3-fa1832cf9961/Payload
    at getAppDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/applesign/index.js:742:13)
    at Applesign.signIPA (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/applesign/index.js:66:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/applesign/bin/applesign.js:52:7).
```

I am a very novice developer and very early days in using Frida such frameworks so any help would very much be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have followed all the available tutorials online. The link provided is one of the too many websites I have visited myself. I can now achieve what I have done so far without Xcode but I still need to have my device connected via USB cable. what I want to do now is to let Frida run whenever someone opens that specific app and I can connect to it via the same network device is connected to. Hope this makes sense. Any suggestions would very much be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

if you are looking for IOS SSL pinning bypass than you can find four techniques [here](https://blog.netspi.com/four-ways-to-bypass-ios-ssl-verification-and-certificate-pinning/).
Two out of four ask to use burp-suite tool, which community edition is free.

Comment: Burp will not help you bypassing  certificate or key pinning of an iOS app. Anyway please do not create answers that mainly consist of a link. Always quote the relevant information in the answer as the link can be dead tomorrow.